# Reading .sav File in Python

Tags: python, spss

I'm trying to read a `.sav` file with Python 3 using [savReaderWriter](https://pypi.org/project/savReaderWriter/):

Here's my code :

```
from savReaderWriter import SavReader

with SavReader(mySavFile, returnHeader = True) as reader:
     header = reader.next()
     for line in reader:
          process(line)
```

I get the following error :

```
OSError: dlopen(/Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/master/src/savreaderwriter/savReaderWriter/spssio/macos/libicuuc48.1.dylib, 6): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libicudata48.1.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/myusername/.virtualenvs/master/src/savreaderwriter/savReaderWriter/spssio/macos/libicuuc48.1.dylib

Reason: image not found
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Indentation and try savReaderWriter.savHeaderReader

Comment: I use the rpy package instead, R can read spss files natively.

Comment: I tried the rpy package. Actually looks like just what I need. But here too I get the same error. "ImportError: Reason: image not found"

Answer (score 0):

I saw this recently with some Java libs and the solution was to symlink the library from its actual location to its expected location. This seems to more closely relate to your particular question.

[Library (dylib) not loaded - image not found - Python IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931915/library-dylib-not-loaded-image-not-found-python-ide)